# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4) when creating multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, lambda

So I wrote a function which enable me depending on what I want to create new column in my dataframe , I wanted to update my function so that , it will create at the same time 4 columns instead of 1 depending on the selected feature.

My function below :

```
def adding_column(file, func_name = 'all'):

    #df = read_excel(file, sheet_name= my_sheet)

    if func_name == 'step1':
        df['column_0'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func0"]), axis=1) 

    elif func_name== 'step2': # you
        df['column_1'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func1"]), axis=1)
    elif func_name== 'step3': # you
        df['column_2'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func2"]), axis=1)

    elif func_name== 'step4':
        df[column_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func3"]), axis=1)

    elif func_name == 'all':
        df['column_0'], df['column_1'], df['column_2'], df['column_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func0","func1","func2","func3"]), axis=1)
        print(df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names =["func0","func1","func2","func3"]), axis=1))
    else:
        raise Exception("Wrong feature type entered.)


    # if you want to take a look a the file
    # print( df.head())
```

```
CreateColumn(df)
```

When running the function I get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-53faabfa700e> in <module>
     38     df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
     39 
---> 40 CreateColumn(df)
     41 
     42 # Another solution

<ipython-input-72-53faabfa700e> in CreateColumn(file, func_name)
     28 
     29    elif func_name == 'all':
---> 30        df['column_0'], df['column_1'], df['column_2'], df['column_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func0","func1","func2","func3"]), axis=1)
      31      print(df.apply(lambda x: process(x['original'], func_names=["func0","func1","func2","func3"]), axis=1))
     32     else:

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

trying to print , just the last function (func3) which display tag appear, how can I handle this

```
0      noun verb noun pron verb noun adj verb noun ad...
1            aux verb noun verb verb adp noun propn pron
2      verb adp noun adp noun pron verb pron verb pro...
3                        noun adp noun adj noun verb adj
4      adv verb noun noun adj noun adj noun adj verb ...
5      adp adj det noun pron verb adp noun verb verb ...
6      noun pron pron verb adp noun adp noun pron pro...
7      adp pron adj propn pron verb adj adp adp verb ...
8      pron pron verb verb adp det noun det noun noun...
```

the process function lokks like this :

```
def process(texte, func_names=[]):
    functions = {"func_o": func_o, #not useful
            "func0": func0,
            "func1": func1,
            "func2": func2,
            "func3": func3}

    for func_name in func_names:
        texte = functions[func_name](texte)

    return texte
```

Comment: The whole problem is just a typo - `df['column_0'], df['column_1'], df['column_3']` are 3 columns, you forgot `column_2`, thus Python cannot unpack 4 values into 3 variables. EDIT: This problem is only in the error, not in the above code. Make sure you ran your correct version.

Comment: hello, even with that I  still get the same error

Comment: Again: "Make sure you ran your correct version.". If the error shows the old code snippet (with 3 columns only), you run wrong code.

Comment: I wrote it bad on stackoverflow, in my terminal all is ok, 4 column 4 function. even when i change to two columns it said , too many values to un pack (expected 2) , It works only when i created ine column not more than 2 at the sametime